# How to initialize vector from array without allocating more storage space?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The direct way to initialize a vector from an array seems to be:

```
int sizeArr; int * array = getArray(sizeArr);
std::vector<int> vec(array, array+sizeArr);
```

Here, I am getting the array from a function which allocates the space in memory and sets `sizeArr` by reference. {start edit} Unfortunately, the function is not written by me and I need to deal with C style array then convert it to a vector somehow. (If possible efficiently). {end edit}

When I initialize `vec`, obviously I am allocating space for it separately. If I have no intention of using the data using `array` anymore, is it possible to somehow "move" the data pointed by `array` to the vector `vec` and not allocate any space for it separately?

Comment: Can't you re-write `getArray` to return a vector?

Comment: So when the destructor for `vec` is called, what will happen to the data?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I expect the data to be removed. In short, I want the data to be handled by the vector functions completely. In essence, I want to just transport all the data from `array` and fit it in `vec.data()`.

Comment: So, return a vector.

Comment: @juanchopanza The function `getArray()` is not really written by me. I would have personally preferred to deal with vectors completely but I am using a library function. After I get the data, I want to use vector functions on data pointed to by `array` so I need to initialize a vector for it.

Although I am doing that currently, I want to improve the efficiency since the data is a bit large.

Comment: I think technically you can do that by creating special allocator but I am afraid that will not worse the effort.

Comment: If you don't need to resize the array then another option would be using `unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `vector`. You may also need to keep track of the size, so maybe `pair<int, unique_ptr<int[]>>`. (This assumes that `getArray` allocates memory using `new[]`. Otherwise you'll need a custom deleter for the `unique_ptr`)

Comment: @user19448 - `I expect the data to be removed`  The vector knows how to remove items it has allocated.  It has no idea how to remove items from something foreign that has been placed in it (if you are trying to do that).  Better you use a smart pointer as others have suggested.

Comment: If memory was allocated in other dll, it should be released there too. So you have to use library interface to release this memory any way...

Comment: @Slava Could you please elaborate? I think it might be worth the effort in my case.

Comment: @user19448 you will have to implement http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator interface call getArray in `allocate()` method and whatever that library provides in `deallocate()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the caller doesn't own the data (i.e. is not in charge of deleting it), then the easiest option might be to write a container-like wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
struct array_wrapper
{
  typedef T* iterator;
  typedef const T* const_iterator;
  array_wrapper(T* begin, T* end) : data_(begin), size_(end-begin) {}
  iterator begin() { return data_; }
  iterator end() { return data_ + size_; }
  const_iterator begin() const { return data_; }
  const_iterator end() const { return data_ + size_; }
  size_t size() const { return size_; }
  T& operator[](size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
  const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }
  void swap(array_wrapper& other) { 
    std::swap(size_, other.size_);
    std::swap(data_, other.data_);
  }
 private:
  T* data_;
  size_t size_;
};
```

then

```
array_wrapper<int> vec(array, array+sizeArr);
```

This has a lot of the functionality of an `std::vector`, but does not own the underlying data, and supports no operations that would result in resizing or re-allocating.

Comment: I think this is perfect for my use case. As others suggested, I will also look into smart pointers.

`and supports no operations that would result in resizing or re-allocating` That is perfectly fine with me.

Comment: @user19448 The thing with smart pointers is that they assume ownership in one way or another.

Comment: @user19448 Note that if you need to `delete[]` the pointer when you are done with it, you need to add a destructor to this type that will correctly do that. (Or you can be fancy and make the template arguments `template <typename T, typename Deleter = std::default_delete<T[]>>`, so that you can use a no-op deleter if you aren't responsible for deleting the pointer.)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you even allocate the memory with a pointer for int?
There is a very high chance, that you have no reason for doing this.

If you have a compiler which assists c++11 it should be possible to just initialize the vector with std::vector vec{array};
Or if you dont need the array anymore, just delete it and push references of the array to the vector