# Wrap raw data in std container like array, with runtime size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, containers, std

Is there any std container which would be fixed size like std::array, but the size would not be compile time, but runtime?

I want to pass a part of some data I have stored in `std::array` to `std::acculumate` and similar functions. I do not want to use std::vector (working on embedded platform), therefore I am looking for something in between.

Assume code like this, what I want is something to be used in place of `array_part`:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::array<float,100> someData;
// fill the data
  int dataCount = 50;
  std::array_part<float> partOfData(someData.data(),dataCount)); // <<<<< here  
  const auto s_x  = std::accumulate(partOfData.begin(), partOfData.end(), 0.0);

}
```

If there is no such container, how can I wrap the raw data I have and present them to `std::accumulate` and other std algorithms?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but: why not just offset iterators? something like `std::accumulate(partOfData.begin(), partOfData.begin() + dataCount, 0.0);`

Comment: I can't make sense out of your question. You want a dynamically sized array type, but you want to pass part of `std::array` to `accumulate`. Then *why* do you need the new array type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::accumulate` takes iterators. You can pass it iterators that contain the range of interest:

```
auto start = partOfData.begin() + 42;
auto end = partOfData.begin() + 77;
const auto s_x  = std::accumulate(start, end, 0.0);
```

Alternatively, you can roll out your own non-owning container-like object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346688/how-to-initialize-vector-from-array-without-allocating-more-storage-space/26346941#26346941) for an example.