# how to transfer ownership from a c++ std::vector<char> to a char *pointer

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have met a situation that, i got a `std::vector<char>` data output from a third-party lib, it is a very big length data, and then I need to convert it a `pybind11::array` object, I don't want to allocate memory and do `memcpy` ,that's not efficient at all.

Now I know I can got the `std::vector<char>` buffer address, but I do not know how to release the vector's ownership so the buffer would not release when the vector object is destructed, I wonder if there's a way to achieve this,.

I have wrote a test code below to test, but it failed

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
int *got_vec(int len){// the len in actually scene is decided by the thirdparty lib

  std::vector<int> vec;
  for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
    vec.push_back(i);
  }
  int *p_vec = &vec[0];
  std::move(vec);
  return p_vec;
}

int main(int argc,const char **argv){
  int len=atoi(argv[1]);

  std::cout<<"will go allocate memory size:"<<len<<", before allocation"<<std::endl; 

  int *p_vec = got_vec(len);
  std::cout<<"after allocation, go to print value"<<std::endl; 
  for(int i = 0; i < len;i++)
   std::cout<<p_vec[i]<<",";
  std::cout<<std::endl;

  delete p_vec;
  std::cout<<"deleted"<<std::endl;
}
```

The program crashed at `std::cout<<p_vec[i]<<",";`

Comment: Would [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) do the trick?

Comment: The line `std::move(vec);` actually does nothing.

Comment: `return p_vec;` will return a pointer to local data, the vector object (and the data it maintains) will end its life once the function returns, the pointer will immediately become invalid. The solution is simple: Return the vector itself instead.

Comment: So you are trying to *steal* the vector's buffer?

Comment: @Fareanor, Thank you for the quick reply, I know what the problem is, i wrote the test code just want to show i want to achieve more cleary, i need to implent the code as in test code and works normally

Comment: @NutCracker, I test the vector::data()，not work, it's actually the same as &vec[0]

Comment: @Timo,yeah, that's what i really want to do

Comment: The only way to steal a vector's contents is to [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) with or move to another vector.

Comment: @rockofz - Why would it be that _the vector object is destructed_? If you _got a std::vector data output from a third-party lib_, isn't it up to you whether and when it is deleted?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, i see the problem , so i am asking help here

Comment: @rockofz AFAIK It is impossible to steal the `std::vector`'s internal buffer. It does not allow that (except if you move or swap to another vector which will not help since you want to get rid of it).

Comment: Given the tag [tag:pybind11] then reading the section [Binding STL containers](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers) makes me think this is the purpose of `bind_vector`?

Answer (score 1):

A std::vector does not allow detaching the underlying buffer. You can also have a look at [taking over memory from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160953/taking-over-memory-from-stdvector) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` doesn't provide way to transfer its buffer.

You have to do some copy (or not use `std::vector` for original buffer).

Comment: That's a shame actually. This could be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course, because this is what the `std::vector` class does for move operation.  But you cannot in a portable way (*). You must find in the internals of the `std::vector` class of your implementation, how the buffer is stored (what attribute is used). Ideally you should search how what the move constructor does with the source vector and do the same. It is likely to just set the internal pointer to NULL, but you should control that.

Simply *as you would be using unspecified internals*, it would only be guaranteed to work on that version of that compiler.

---

On a philosophical point of view, we as the programmers are expected to use the classes of the standard library *as they are*. There are few extension points, and few classes allow to be derived. It is just the opposite of Java which provides abstract classes to help the programmer to build its own custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly 'steal' memory from an `std::vector`, but maybe you don't need to steal it in the 1st place.

I'm not familiar with `pybind11::array`, but since you want the data pointer from `std::vector`, I'm guessing you can construct it from data that was allocated somewhere else.

Maybe all you need is a wrapper class, that would keep your data inside a `std::vector`, while providing a view into it through `pybind11::array`.

```cpp
class Wrapper {
public:
  Wrapper(std::vector<char>);
  pybind11::array asArray();

private:
  std::vector<char> m_data
}
```

You can then use `std::move` to efficiently transfer data between `std::vector`s, without copying it around.

Comment: it's a sad news that this workaround would not work, even if pybind11::array could construct from array, it still need to do memory allocation and memcpy, it can't steal the memory ownership of the vector. because the python object is used outside of the c++ side and we dont know when it would be released,  the pybind11::array should own the memory and release it by itself later.   
this is really surprised at me for my expectation of what c++ can do !