# Constructing a std::vector<T> from a T* pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, stl

I tried googling for an answer but I was wondering if it is possible to construct a `std::vector<T>` from a `T*` pointer?

I looked at the API docs and it looks like it's not possible from the given constructors and the C++11 `data()` is for the container's allocation.

I am asking as I have a memory mapped file that returns a `int*` and it would be great to re-use a class that extensively uses `std::vector<T>`

I am looking for something like this:

```
const size_t n = ...
int* map = mmap(....);
std::vector<int> vec(map, n);
```

Comment: Do you mean making a copy, or reusing an existing buffer?

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec(map, map + n);` will instantiate a vector with the first `n` ints pointed at by `map`.

Comment: @PavelMinaev I have already allocated memory from the mmap() function so I want it to reuse this allocation rather than the container creating an internal allocation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346688/how-to-initialize-vector-from-array-without-allocating-more-storage-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` is all about managing it's buffers.  As items are pushed into the container it may delete and reallocate new buffer.  It wouldn't make sense for `std::vector` to take control of an existing vector as it may end up trying to delete and reallocate.

If you want you can write a custom allocator for your vector that uses mmap, but you can't make a vector take control of an existing buffer.

If you take away the requirements of memory management, the interface for vector is pretty simple and it wouldn't take much to write a compatible wrapper around your mmap'ed buffer.